# salesforce loading an iframe

Tags: visualforce, iframe

In Salesforce, I have a remote site setup to go to a specified URL... In a vf page, I go to load the site with this line:

```
<iframe src="https://myURL.com" />
```

However, I get an SSL error. I also tried the apex:iframe option... Does anyone have a work around? Ultimately the vf page needs to be displayed as a custom console component.

There is nothing in the preview and response sections... this is what i am getting back in headers:

Request URL:https://sit.mylinkhere.com/
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/shopperrecapembed
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
displayType:desktop

Thanks

Comment: What's the SSL error? Can you post the response you see over the network?

Comment: Does the SSL error happen when you load the URL in a separate browser window?

Comment: no the error only happens when loading the vf page. how can i log the error?... i am very new to front-end dev

Comment: In Chrome (and other browsers have equivalent tools), open the Developer Tools and click on the Network tab. Then open the page you have the problem with. The failed request should be listed and if you click on it you will be able to see the HTTPS request made and the response that came back.

Comment: Tyler: You posted the request, which is what your browser is sending to the server. Can you post the response, which is the other end? In Chrome's Developer Tools, Network tab: click on the entry for your link, the select Headers from the tab and scroll down to Response Headers. Also, go to the Response tab and see what that shows.

Comment: It doesn't look like the response headers come through... The status just says (pending) and there is no response in the headers, only the request.

Comment: This is blocked by your Chrome browser. Click the little shield in the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the site you posted (`https://sit.mylinkhere.com/`) is using an invalid SSL certificate. The SSL certificate I'm presented with when I view that site is for `dm2.fastdomain.com`.

The problem is likely that your client is blocking this site because of the invalid SSL certificate. Your best bet is to fix the SSL certificate and try again.

If you continue to get errors after fixing the SSL certificate, you might want to verify that the site allows framing. Several things including [framebusting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), the [X-Frames-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), etc. can be used to prevent a website from being framed.